# Android: BootReceiver & other Receiver getting Called

Tags: android, receiver

So my mention is to have a Boot Receiver which will re set the Alarm when the device is booted up.(Which work now)

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

The Time I set when i want to fire up my alarm.

```
 alarm.set(actual.get(Calendar.YEAR) ,actual.get(Calendar.MONTH), actual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hours,minutes, 0);
```

Set the Alarm

```
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

So when testing the BootReceiver its sets the alarm correctly. AlarmReceiver is called which displays a simple notification.

Problem: The Notification is shown on every Boot which I dont get.It only should display the notification when the alarm is triggerd.

So what ive overlooked?

Comment: If the alarm fires immediately upon setting it, it means you've given a date/time in the past.

Comment: Yes of course. Thats what i get for coding after 00:00. Reminder was set to 1:30 am . Changing the Time to future and testing the reboot dont causes the notfication. Ty